# How to implement sqoop in java

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

I am new in hadoop. I am trying to export the data from RDMS into HDFS using sqoop. I am implementing this through command line prompt. I found a guide to implementation of sqoop in java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229611/how-to-use-sqoop-in-java-program), but where can I find the sqoop.jar file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.1-incubating).