# Maven repo for Sqoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, cloudera, sqoop

I'm trying to get Sqoop running on Java, and found the following question:
[How to use Sqoop in Java Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229611/how-to-use-sqoop-in-java-program)

Seems like this is exactly what I need except I'm having trouble finding a maven repo for the "scoop jar".  I am using cdh4.2 and our sqoop version is Sqoop 1.4.2-cdh4.2.1

Note: I have added a repo, but am still unable to access objects like ExportTool(), ExportTool(), or even Sqoop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maven repo for this artifact is for instance: https://mvnrepository.com
(exactly look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.2-cdh4.2.1)

At your pom file you have to add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2-cdh4.2.1</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, I was able to add the repo with no problems, but I guess my problem is something else all together.. How can I access such objects like :ExportTool(), ExportTool(), or even Sqoop? The jar doesn't seem to help there.

Comment: @Tyrick For Sqoop use import org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop

Comment: For ExportTool use import org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool

Comment: Okay, "The import org.apache.sqoop cannot be resolved" when I hover over org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool in Eclipse.  For some reason I am having issues with that path

Comment: Did you try to use mvn clean command or from Eclipse: Project -> Clean?

Comment: ya, =/ Doesn't seem to do it

Comment: <type>pom</type> needed to be removed.  Thanks a ton though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cloudera distribution of Hadoop (CDH), you should also use Cloudera maven repository and not third party site. You can find instructions in the [installation guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_31.html).