# How to print the return code of a Sqoop Error?

Tags: database, oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am writing a script to log all the return code  of any errors occurring when executing a  sqoop operation?

```
for eg we have different sqoop tools like:

sqoop eval, sqoop import, sqoop export etc.
```

When execution one of the tools we would get a return code. If the execution was success ful we get return code=0. If not successful we get some other return code based the type of the error.

Is there any way we can log these errors and return code?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Java code:

Use Sqoop.runTool api.

```
int ret = Sqoop.runTool(yourcommand.toArray(new String[yourcommand.size()]));
```

Please refer to this for more info: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229611/how-to-use-sqoop-in-java-program)

Hope this helps.