# I am trying Sqoop import from oracle to hdfs through java programming

Tags: java, oracle, bash, hadoop, sqoop

I am using ssh to execute Sqoop commands. This is the reference for my code [How to use Sqoop in Java Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229611/how-to-use-sqoop-in-java-program)

But I'm getting an error as "sqoop command not found". This is the code

```js
package sqoop;

import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.Result;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.SSHExec;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.ConnBean;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.CustomTask;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.impl.ExecCommand;

public class TestSSH {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{


    ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("172.17.13.47", "miracle","miracle");

    SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
    ssh.connect();
    CustomTask sampleTask2 = new ExecCommand("sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.13.47:1521/xe --username ouser --password oracleuser --table BRANCH --target-dir /user/branch -m 1");
    Result res = ssh.exec(sampleTask2);
    if (res.isSuccess)
    {
        System.out.println("Return code: " + res.rc);
        System.out.println("sysout: " + res.sysout);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Return code: " + res.rc);
        System.out.println("error message: " + res.error_msg);
    }
    
    ssh.disconnect();   
}
}
```

The error it shows is : "Execution failed while executing command:
Error message: bash: sqoop: command not found"
I have added the sshxcute jar file too.

But when I try that Sqoop command on terminal, it works perfectly.
Please let me know how I can achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to set sqoop home in your bash profile or else pass the complete installation path like <installation_path>/bin/sqoop

Comment: I have already set sqoop home in bash profile. And when I run sqoop commands on terminal,they just work fine.

Comment: what about the else part i mentioned

Comment: could you please tell me where or how to pass the installation path in the above program.

Comment: CustomTask sampleTask2 = new ExecCommand("<installation_path>/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.13.47:1521/xe --username ouser --password oracleuser --table BRANCH --target-dir /user/branch -m 1");

Comment: Happy it helped.I added these comments as answer , could you accept it , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set sqoop home in your bash profile or else pass the complete installation path like /bin/sqoop.

The below is the change that you need to add in your code :

```
  CustomTask sampleTask2 = new ExecCommand("<installation_path>/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.13.47:1521/xe --username ouser --password oracleuser --table BRANCH --target-dir /user/branch -m 1");
```