# how to import data using Sqoop java api?

Tags: scala, sqoop

I want to import data use sqoop, but I don't want to use shell command. So how to use Java API to do this.The Sqoop version is 1.4.6, and I use Scala + SBT to do it. by the way, which dependencies I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was needing to use *Sqoop* to import data from **MySQL** to **Hive** using *Scala* inside a *Cloudera CDH 5.7* cluster, so I started by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283262/4474204).

The problem was that it was not getting the right configurations when it was being executed on the server.

Executing Sqoop manually was something like this:

```
sqoop import --hive-import --connect "jdbc:mysql://host/db" \
--username "username" --password "password" --table "viewName" \
--hive-table "outputTable" -m 1 --check-column "dateColumnName" \
--last-value "lastMinDate" --incremental append
```

So at the end I chose to execute it as an external process using Scala's `sys.process.ProcessBuilder`. It does not require any SBT dependency for running this way. Finally the runner was implemented this way:

```
import sys.process._

def executeSqoop(connectionString: String, username: String, password: String, 
                   viewName: String, outputTable: String, 
                   dateColumnName: String, lastMinDate: String) = { 
  // To print every single line the process is writing into stdout and stderr respectively
  val sqoopLogger = ProcessLogger(
    normalLine => log.debug(normalLine),
    errorLine => errorLine match {
      case line if line.contains("ERROR") => log.error(line)
      case line if line.contains("WARN") => log.warning(line)
      case line if line.contains("INFO") => log.info(line)
      case line => log.debug(line)
    }
  )

  // Create Sqoop command, every parameter and value must be a separated String into the Seq
  val command = Seq("sqoop", "import", "--hive-import",
    "--connect", connectionString,
    "--username", username,
    "--password", password,
    "--table", viewName,
    "--hive-table", outputTable,
    "-m", "1",
    "--check-column", dateColumnName,
    "--last-value", lastMinDate,
    "--incremental", "append")

  // result will contain the exit code of the command
  val result = command ! sqoopLogger
  if (result != 0) {
    log.error("The Sqoop process did not finished successfully")
  } else {
    log.info("The Sqoop process finished successfully")
  }
}
```