# Sqoop Export -D sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100

Tags: java, sqoop

I'm trying to do sqoop through java api. The export command contains a parameter with -D sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100. How can I give this parameter in java api?

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: From terminal ,  Sqoop export -D sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100 --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver --username user --password password              using java api,                                                                                                      SqoopOptions options =new SqoopOptions();
 options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dbname");
 options.setUsername("root");
 options.setPassword("root");                                                                           How can i give "sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100" in java api?

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer in this question can give you some directions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229611/how-to-use-sqoop-in-java-program